# Calculate a plot and intersect on a curve in an excel chart based on a single value

Tags: excel, plot, charts, intersect

I have some data that I'm using to plot a curve in excel. It uses a non-linear calculation.

The calculation is called the rule of twelfths - it is used to calculate changes in tidal height between a high and low tide. The rule states that in the first sixth (often approximated to an hour) of the time period, the tide will move 1/12th of the overall range. In the second sixth, the tide will move 2/12th's of the overall range. In the 3rd and 4th sixth, the tide will move 3/12ths (in each), and then it will move 2/12ths again in the fifth sixth, and 1/12th in the final sixth.

The maths for this is relatively straightforward - if I know the High Water Time and Low Water time, and their respective heights, I can calculate a data point for each sixth. That then plots to a nice even curve (and some fun pie chart shenanigans shows it on a clock face too).

This produces the following sheet:
[image: Excel Screen Grab]

What I am now after is the ability to overlay onto that the height for a given time of day. This would be used in a 'live' sense to display the height 'now', or perhaps where the user dragged their finger on the curve if it was in an app. I'm only using this for screenshot/flat file purposes, so I just need it to base the overlay one the data in one cell.

So, in the attached screenshot, if we had a time of day of 1128, (based on Cell J3), excel would take the time in J3, and wherever it intersected the curve, draw both a vertical and a horizontal line, so that the height of tide data (HOT) could be measured off that axis.

This would look something like this (I've circled cell J3 too):

[image: Annotated Excel Tide Screenshot]

Is that something that's possible? It might be that it needs to do a lookup in the table of calculated data points and then interpolate just between those two - that would probably get close enough.

A two stage question I guess - firstly calculating the intercept, secondly getting it to draw on (complete with the vertical and horizontal lines if possible!).

There's a widget on planetcalc which does *almost* the same thing - it only gives the calculated data points (and it uses hours rather than the range), but it gives a nice visual idea.

[PlanetCalc Tide Calculator](https://planetcalc.com/2450/)

Any thoughts? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I created a solution to this myself in the end.

Given that the two values were easily calculated, I produced a pair of values for the desired time/height, and plotted each as an additional line graph on top of the existing (styled correctly).

This gave the appearance of what I wanted, and intersected my curve perfectly.